# Saving child form information to parent case

Tags: commcare

I have a form that is in a module for a child case (individual), but I want to be able to save a calculation that happens in the form to the parent case (household).

Is there a way to save this property/informatoin in this individual-case form to the household-case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can save the particular question from a child case form that you wish to save as the property to the parent case by typing "parent/[property name]" in the case management settings page of the child case form.

See the "Accessing Parent Case Properties" on the CommCare help wiki (link here: https://wiki.commcarehq.org/display/commcarepublic/Child+Cases).